# JQuery background position syntax

Tags: jquery, css, syntax

```
var a= $('li.current-menu-item').position().left;
var b= $('li.current-menu-item').parent().position().left;
var c= a-b;

$('li.current-menu-item').parent().css('background-position', c + " 3" )
```

I don't know what is the right syntax for using a variable and number in the last line

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the pixels value:

```
$('li.current-menu-item').parent().css('background-position', c + "px 3px" )
```

Comment: hey why you didn't use ul at the place of li because li's parent is always ul then you can write code like this also : $('ul').css('background-position', c+"px 3px" )

Comment: Yep, but could possible affect other ul's too.

Comment: then we can directly put a class or id on ul then it should be some easy and some short also.

Comment: Yep. But I just copied the code of the OP and made the correct change.

Comment: hahaha gud ...... never mind just kidding okay i understand, you just solved the problem. but i think in that one more mistake here is no space between li and class name..

Comment: No. otherwise you select a child of `li` with that classname.

Comment: then why you place li you can directly use $('.current-menu-item') , I am asking because is there any reason for that one can we use this also or not.. some confusion that's y

Comment: Because `li.current-menu-item` is more specific. Like in case there are more elements with the `current-menu-item` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to add css of li's parent that means you want to add css on ul

```
$('ul').css('background-position', c+"px 3px" );
```

At the place of :

$('li.current-menu-item').parent().css('background-position', c + "px 3px" );

If you want to add css on li's parent because li's parent is always ul and if you want to add class on current -menu-item parent then you need to add space between li and class name like :

```
$('li .current-menu-item').parent().css('background-position',c+"px 3px");
```

else it can give error to you. thanks gud luck